# Find all the childs who have the same parents than the element hovered in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parents

I have a list of subject. Inside each subject, i have items.
When i hover an item, i try to change the color of each item of this subject.

```
<div class="subject">
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hello2</div>
    <div class="item">hello3</div>
</div>

<div class="subject">
    <div class="item">hello</div>
    <div class="item">hello2</div>
    <div class="item">hello3</div>
</div>
```

I if do like that, it change all the .items of the whole page :

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    $(".item").addClass("hovering");
}, function () {
    $(".item").removeClass("hovering");
});
```

I can't find how to say "All the child who have the same parent than the item i'm hovering"...
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

change your JS to this:

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hovering");
}, function () {
    $(".item").removeClass("hovering");
});
```

here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ9zb/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.item').addClass("hovering");
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.item').removeClass("hovering");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lh79e/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
   $(this).siblings().addClass("hovering");
 }, function () {
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("hovering");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6n9b/)

Answer (score 0):

i have created a jsfiddle please go through this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
  $(".item").hover(function () {

    $(this).addClass("hovering");
   }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hovering");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8qep/49/

thanks